# URL Redirection in Multisite wordpress

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

We have multi-site wordpress containing more then 50 blogs/sub-site.

Our base URL to wordpress site is www.example.com/base-site/ and we have other  sub-sites in it like www.example.com/base-site/site1 site2 ... etc.

Now My question is to redirect the main-site to one of the subsites but a simple redirect 301  is not working. I tried some solutions of mod-rewrite but its not working either for this main-site to redirect to sub-site.

A solution is required to Redirect

```
www.example.com/base-site/
```

to

```
www.example.com/base-site/site1
```

Solution used so far but not working for me [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790207/htaccess-rewrite-wordpress-multisite) [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594577/redirect-main-site-to-subsite-in-multisite-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66115/redirect-main-site-to-subsite-in-multisite-wordpress) If someone want to redirect the main wordpress site to its sub-site, just create the `redirect.php` file in the `wp-content/plugins/`  directory and put the code mentioned in the post, replace the url with your own and name of the main site in the `IF` condition.